# How to setup laravel hasOne relationships with itself?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on an application in Laravel where users can be matched up with one users. I am trying to figure out how to setup the hasOne relationship between users.

Here is how I have done it so far. Users when they are created have a match_id which represents the user that they are matched to. When they are matched this record gets updated. Here is my table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('event_id');
        $table->foreign('event_id')->references('id')->on('events')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('match_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('match_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

In the user model I have set up this relationship:

```
 public function match() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

but as of right now I cannot do something like this and get the expected matched user's information:

```
$user->match()->get();
```

After reading the [docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships), I see that in such situations you can setup the foreign key and local key. Nevertheless I am having a difficult time figuring this out.

Could someone give me some guidance on how I could do this? I am also open to any suggestions on different implementations.

-----edit------
after discussing with some people in the comments I made some progress in my endeavors. I am able to get some results and have experimented by logging the matches. For whatever reason though I am getting the wrong matches. Look below for more information:

in my controller I log the users name and match after it has been formed:

```
Log::error($user->match);
Log::error('has matched with:');

Log::error($user);
Log::error('participant:');
```

in the database here are the users and their matches:
[image]

yet in the logs, the match is not the same:
[image]

Comment: Is this bi-directional? If `User A` matches `User B`, does `User B` also match `User A`?

Comment: Just adding the foreign key didn't work? `return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'match_id);`

Comment: Hi there @TimLewis, no it is not bi-directional. User A could be matched with User B who is matched with User C

Comment: Then the logic you have should work, but as suggested, modify the relationship to explicitly use `match_id`; it might be looking for something else. Then, you should be able to do `$user->match` to see what user they are matched with, or `null`. Note; don't use `get()` on a relationship that only returns a single record, you don't want a `Collection` here.

Comment: @kerbholz Hello! I just tried it again and it did not work. I am checking it by hitting a controller and Log::error($user->match()->get()); When I check on Telescope all I get are empty arrays

Comment: @TimLewis when I do not use get I get this error: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne could not be converted to string

Comment: Seems you are using Log class to """debug"""". Try `Log::error($user->match->id);`

Comment: Are you using `$user->match()`? Cause that's not right either. Use `$user->match`, or `$user->match()->first()`.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte when I do that I get: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: @TimLewis when doing what you suggestted I get nothing. Is it possibly because I don't have a belongsTo relationship as well? Just spitballing cause I have no clue why this is not working out

Comment: Try replacing `hasOne` with `hasMany` and then use `$user->match()->get()`

Comment: No, it means that since `match_id` is `nullable()`, `$user->match` **can return `null`**. Do you have a record in your database with `match_id` that equals another record's `id`? Welcome to the wonderful world of debugging relationships :) There's a lot to learn. Also, I think this might be a `belongsTo()` relationship; having the `match_id` on the same table is the same idea as a `parent` relationship, which is definitely a `belongsTo()`

Comment: @TimLewis your last comment led me down a good rabbit hole. I discovered that where I was logging it from, the matches had not been done. I have since fixed it, and the relationship $user->match now shows something. HOWEVER, it is showing the wrong thing. For example, if we have User A, B, and C, User A could be matched with User B in the database, but for whatever reason logs User C, and then one of the users will log nothing

Comment: Excellent; that's a step in the right direction. It might help if you provide a screenshot with the 3 records in your database, specifically `id` and `match_id` and how you're querying them/accessing the relationships (but post that part as code, not a screenshot). Oh, and did you modify your relationship to a `belongsTo()`?

Comment: @TimLewis I have editted the original post with a case test that shows the problem!

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see `match_id` in that screenshot; are you using `draw_id` instead?

Comment: @TimLewis i did change match_id to draw_id, so it was the same thing. It turns out that Nicolas Goosen's answer seems to work. Thank you so much for all the time and effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the match_id is on the users table, the relationship should be belongsTo, not hasOne. 
belongsTo is specified on the model that contains the foreign key.

Also, you should specify the foreign key:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'match_id');
```